# Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Long]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using `Java 8` with `Spring 4.3.1.RELEASE`, `Hibernate 5.2.1.Final` and `MySQL` running on a `Wildfly 10` Server.

I have some Java code that was working when I ran my server on a Windows machine. But since I move the exact same code to an MacOS (Sierra) machine, I get the following.

I get the following **error**:

> org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException:
>   Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type
>   [java.lang.Long]; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException:
>   For input string: "null"

To me it looks like there is an error as a result of a `String` being assigned to a `Long`. As you can see in the code below, the `avatar` column is a `byte[]` with a `@Lob` annotation.

More detail:

```
19:07:23,287 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] (default task-3) Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Long]; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
19:07:23,423 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] (default task-5) Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Failed to decode VALUE_STRING as base64 (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS): Illegal character ':' (code 0x3a) in base64 content
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@57905ec8; line: 19, column: 20]
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@57905ec8; line: 19, column: 13] (through reference chain: com.jobs.spring.domain.Person["avatar"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Failed to decode VALUE_STRING as base64 (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS): Illegal character ':' (code 0x3a) in base64 content
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@57905ec8; line: 19, column: 20]
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@57905ec8; line: 19, column: 13] (through reference chain: com.jobs.spring.domain.Person["avatar"])
19:07:29,140 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] (default task-6) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

My code is as follows:

**Person.java**

```
import javax.persistence.*;
    ...

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
public class Person extends AbstractDomain<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "UID")
    private String uid;

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "AVATAR", nullable = true)
    private byte[] avatar;

    @XmlElement
    public byte[] getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(byte[] avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }
}
```

**MySQL person table**

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: well it says your input string you give it is null so that's why you get a number format exception

Comment: You're right. Apologies for the simple question. I think the issue is my client is passing a null value to the RESTful service.

Comment: `Illegal character ':' (code 0x3a) in base64 content`